# Disable DRF throttling for some users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a few test users that are used to run integration tests against my Django + DRF application. How can I disable throttling for these users only?

Looks like I can override DRF's `allow_request()` method (see https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/99e8b4033efa44930ace40fb48a4d7bcd224f9fb/rest_framework/throttling.py#L109):

```
from rest_framework.throttling import SimpleRateThrottle

class CustomSimpleRateThrottle(SimpleRateThrottle):
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        if request.user in {<user1>, <user2>}:
            return True
        return super().allow_request(request, view)
```

But I'd rather not choose this approach because it requires me to have to use this base method in all my throttling classes (e.g. `UserRateThrottle`, `AnonRateThrottle`, etc.).

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the throttling is implemented as a check against a cached list of requests timestamps [keyed on a unique string per user and per scope](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/99e8b4033efa44930ace40fb48a4d7bcd224f9fb/rest_framework/throttling.py#L193), I suppose you could use a custom middleware that clears the value for the cache keys matching those users. Something that would run this function on incoming requests (assuming an `allowed_users` iterable for `{<user_1>, <user_2>}`):

```py
from django.cache import cache as default_cache

def clear_throttling_for_allowed_users(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated and user in allowed_users:
        # Based on the implementation of UserRateThrottle.get_cache_key()
        cache_key = f'throttle_user_{user.pk}'
        default_cache.delete(cache_key)
```

or if you know you've defined more scopes on top of the default 'user' scope which handle throttling for authenticated users:

```py
USER_THROTTLE_SCOPES = ['user', 'another_scope', 'one_more']

def clear_throttling_for_allowed_users(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated and user in allowed_users:
        for scope in THROTTLE_SCOPES:
            cache_key = f'throttle_{scope}_{user.pk}'
            default_cache.delete(cache_key)
```

Comment: Can't edit it, because it's less than 6 characters, but I think it should be `cache_key = f'throttle_{scope}_{user.pk}'` instead of `cache_key = f'throttle_{user}_{user.pk}'`

Comment: @PTomasz Indeed, good shout thank you. I've made the edit.